# Titan: Lock owner waits for own lock causing com.sleepycat.je.LockTimeoutException

Tags: locking, titan, tinkerpop3

I have a multi-threaded web application using [Tinkerpop 3](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/) and [Titan Graph DB](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/) plus a local Berkeley storage backend. Occasionally, commits fail due to exceptions like:

> Transaction *x* **owns** *y*
>
> Transaction *x* **waits for** *y*

Which is of course puzzling me. How come the lock owner times out waiting for its own lock? The same commit/rollback operation is always attempted up to 3 times with a backoff time of 1s and 1.5s after the first and second approach, respecively. I am also making sure that transactions do not leak between requests (always rolling back at the start and end of each request). At last, I try to release any locks as soon as possible. Any hints?

### Some Examples

Example Exception 1

```
Caused by: com.sleepycat.je.LockTimeoutException: (JE 5.0.73) Lock expired. Locker 1437370674 2837_jWebSocket TCP-Connector 01.52499.3_Txn: waited for lock on database=edgestore LockAddr:1418570977 LSN=0x0/0x7498 type=WRITE grant=WAIT_PROMOTION timeoutMillis=500 startTime=1486450928285 endTime=1486450928785
Owners: [<LockInfo locker="1437370674 2837_jWebSocket TCP-Connector 01.52499.3_Txn" type="READ"/>, <LockInfo locker="1628779116 2189_pool-4-thread-1_Txn" type="READ"/>]
Waiters: []
Transaction 1437370674 2837_jWebSocket TCP-Connector 01.52499.3_Txn owns LockAddr:1418570977 <LockInfo locker="1437370674 2837_jWebSocket TCP-Connector 01.52499.3_Txn" type="READ"/>
Transaction 1437370674 2837_jWebSocket TCP-Connector 01.52499.3_Txn waits for LockAddr:1418570977
```

Example Exception 2

```
Caused by: com.sleepycat.je.LockTimeoutException: (JE 5.0.73) Lock expired. Locker 1938532737 6471_ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1_Txn: waited for lock on database=edgestore LockAddr:2056488084 LSN=0x0/0x5a1db type=WRITE grant=WAIT_PROMOTION timeoutMillis=500 startTime=1486457805980 endTime=1486457806480
Owners: [<LockInfo locker="1938532737 6471_ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1_Txn" type="READ"/>, <LockInfo locker="1223191726 6475_pool-16-thread-1_Txn" type="READ"/>]
Waiters: []
Transaction 1938532737 6471_ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1_Txn owns LockAddr:2056488084 <LockInfo locker="1938532737 6471_ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1_Txn" type="READ"/>
Transaction 1938532737 6471_ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1_Txn waits for LockAddr:2056488084
```

Example Exception 3

```
Caused by: com.sleepycat.je.LockTimeoutException: (JE 5.0.73) Lock expired. Locker 1723301468 1446_pool-3-thread-1_Txn: waited for lock on database=edgestore LockAddr:1184880090 LSN=0x0/0xa966 type=WRITE grant=WAIT_PROMOTION timeoutMillis=500 startTime=1486730956580 endTime=1486730957080
Owners: [<LockInfo locker="1577323761 1489_Thread-41_Txn" type="READ"/>, <LockInfo locker="1723301468 1446_pool-3-thread-1_Txn" type="READ"/>, <LockInfo locker="1845682412 1451_Thread-40_Txn" type="READ"/>]
Waiters: [<LockInfo locker="2126118378 1517_Thread-42_Txn" type="READ"/>]
Transaction 1723301468 1446_pool-3-thread-1_Txn owns LockAddr:1184880090 <LockInfo locker="1723301468 1446_pool-3-thread-1_Txn" type="READ"/>
Transaction 1723301468 1446_pool-3-thread-1_Txn waits for LockAddr:1184880090
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue no longer exists using [Titan's](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/) successor [JanusGraph](http://janusgraph.org). I presume it was a bug within the [Titan](http://titan.thinkaurelius.com/) code base.

Comment: Still facing the same with janus graph on berkeley db:
com.sleepycat.je.LockTimeoutException: (JE 7.3.7)
Owners: [<LockInfo locker="1079061549 -1_pool-57-thread-2_HandleLocker" type="READ"/>]
Waiters: [<LockInfo locker="326496881 117_pool-57-thread-1_Txn" type="WRITE"/>, <LockInfo locker="879364248 118_pool-57-thread-3_Txn" type="WRITE"/>]

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @VatsalPrakash No, sorry. I always end up with lock timeouts on Berkeley eventually, even with the latest JanusGraph version. Using Cassandra as storage instead avoids this problem.

Comment: Thanks @Double M 
.. :) Same Here... 
I also had to migrate to embedded hbase as a quick fix...